# How to set spring boot active profile in Gradle 4.7

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, profile

**Overall:**
I'm trying to run gradle build task for a specific spring profile but I've got an  error in passing following test:

```
au.com.mnpd.security.JwtTokenUtilTest > generateToken_succeeds FAILED
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

The test is using some properties from spring **development** profile (*located in application-development.yaml*). But I couldn't find any way to pass active profile to gradle build command. 
I tried followings but again the same issue:

```
- gradlew -Dspring.profiles.active=development build

- gradlew -Pdevelopment build
```

**Question:**
Is there anyway to pass active profile to gradle (v 4.7) **build** task like what is applicable for **bootRun** task as follows:

```
bootRun {
        bootRun.systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'development'
}
```

**Note:** I tried the same for build but **build.systemProperty** method does not exist for build task.

As I'm new in gradle, I'd be grateful is you could share your genuine solutions with me.

Answer (score 16):

What you are looking for is setting system properties on the `Test` task, which is what will run your unit tests:

```
test {
  systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'development'
}
```

**Edited after comment - leaving the original answer below as it may still be useful.**

Gradle does not know the way `bootRun` exposes its system properties.

You thus have to add a configuration in your build script, to expose what you need to the Gradle command line.

Something like:

```
bootRun {
    bootRun.systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', "${springProfile}"
}
```

and then have a default in `gradle.properties`:

```
springProfile = development
```

and possibly override the value on the command line:

```
./gradlew -PspringProfile=test build
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I'm looking for doing the same for build not bootRun. Everything works fine in bootRun but I don't know how to do the same for "build" task.

Comment: How to say that profile is default, e.g. `application.properties`?

Answer (score 5):

If you using gradle boot run you need to add this to your build.gradle file

```
bootRun {
    String activeProfile =  System.properties['spring.profiles.active']
    systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", activeProfile
}
```

and then at the time of building you can use gradle bootRun -Dspring.profiles.active=test

or to build you can use 
gradle build -Dspring.profiles.active=test

Comment: why don't you try adding argument 'spring.profiles.active=dev' while runing. make sure u have respective property file available

Answer (score 5):

Gradle files should not depend on your spring profile, unless you explicitly wish that thing.

To run your app with specific profile, use :

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=myprofile ./gradlew bootRun
```

Answer (score 1):

in build.gradle:

```
task 'testCi' (type: Test) {
    useJUnit()
    jvmArgs "-Dspring.profiles.active=ci"
}

task 'testLocal' (type: Test) {
    useJUnit()
    jvmArgs "-Dspring.profiles.active=local"
}
```

I've just been bitten by the way Gradle handle this using Gradle 6.x,
I have two separate test tasks in which I want to run the same tests with either a local or CI configuration.

Tests use Junit platform, for which Gradle spawns a new JVM. As far as I can tell systemProperties is not passed down to the JVM running tests, but jvmArgs will specifically pass properties to the test JVM.

Using env vars as Eugene suggests also works as the child JVM normally inherits env from its parent.