# Can I pass an internal Spring Boot variable to gradlew?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-profiles

I have a question. In my app, I do have several configurations:

```
application-prod.properties
application-test.properties
application-dev.properties
```

and the main file:

```
application.properties
```

Containing one line:

```
spring.profiles.active=test
```

To build and run the app I am using `./gradlew buildNeeded`

Can I somehow pass the properties suffix: test, prod, dev so it is used in the build process, so I can make different bash scripts to run the installation process on test and prod servers?

I am looking for something like `./gradlew buildNeeded --spring.profiles.active=test` or anything that will work...

Comment: this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50665667/how-to-set-spring-boot-active-profile-in-gradle-4-7/50719594

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using spring-gradle-plugin.

From plugin documentation [Passing arguments to your application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#running-your-application-passing-arguments)

> Like all JavaExec tasks, arguments can be passed into bootRun from the
>   command line using --args='' when using Gradle 4.9 or
>   later. For example, to run your application with a profile named dev
>   active the following command can be used:

```
./gradlew bootRun --args='--spring.profiles.active=dev'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use project properties:

```
task buildNeeded {
    doLast {
        def springProfile = project.properties.getOrDefault('spring.profiles.active', 'test')
        println springProfile
    }
}
```

Then you can run the project with

```
./gradlew buildNeeded -Pspring.profiles.active=test
```